# Set EditText visibility based on Spinner value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-event

I'm trying to create this dialog:

[image: dialog].

When Spinner is set to *custom* value, TextEdit should automatically appear. I'm calling `View.setVisible()` on the `TextView` but the visibility is **not evaluated immediately** but waits to another change - e.g. adding another row or setting a date.

The code:

```
        ...
        customText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_custom_text);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                SpinnerItem si = (SpinnerItem) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                evt.type = si.eventType;
                if (evt.type == EventType.CUSTOM) {
                    customText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    customText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                //do nothing
            }
        });
```

I tried `View.invalidate()` (on parent view) and `View.refreshDrawableState()` with no luck :/

Edit: The code above is reached (verified by debugger) and I also tried `View.INVISIBLE`. The view is just not refreshed immediately but only after another change in view.

Comment: what is s? is it spinner

Comment: if its spinner for which you want to show/ hide the edittext then please follow my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, could it be that your layout somehow doesn't allow/recognises this change perhaps?

Try changing it to `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`, including (important!) in your layout xml file.

If that works for some reason, try something like this:

```
customText.getParent().requestLayout(); //possibly the parent of that etc
```

Comment: I've tried but with no luck. Do you think, that the code above should work and the problem might be somewhere else?
Funny thing is that other changes (such as changing button label) works...

Comment: From the code you are showing it should work indeed. Only thing I can think of is that `if` statement, you are sure you are reaching it? The comparison is working, can see it in the debugger etc? No exceptions occur?

Comment: Yes, the statement is reached, `setVisible()` is called etc. Thanks for assuring that I'm on right way - I will try to rewrite the activity...

Comment: you 're actually in a wrong way?  it is callled for an instance not for your displayed view

Answer (score 1):

For Example see this

```
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    if ("YES".equals(s.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase())) {
    youredittxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if ("NO".equals(s.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase())) {
youredittxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}}
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up question, are you in the main UI thread? Because Android have some built in features and policies, so only the owning thread will be able to change the UI.
If you are outside the same thread, try:

```
customText.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        customText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: In the example code given in the question it is in the `OnItemSelectedListener` at least.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that you are actually reaching your code block.

> ```
>  customText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
> ```